# Blender modeling don’ts and things to avoid?

Tags: modeling

Hi i’d really appreciate if someone could give me the “10 commandments” so to speak of blender modeling. A lot of the resources out there discuss what you CAN do in blender but sparingly what you CANT or SHOULDNT do. Like I randomly stumble upon tips like- don’t have faces on top of faces or  make sure your normals point outward. I was hoping someone could list some things to look out for. I’m planning to render pictures using objects made in blender on other programs such as SFM or Daz. I was hoping there would be some universal modeling rules to keep in mind. Thanks!!

Comment: Open ended opinion based questions are not a good fit for this site, [according to the rules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) Perhaps ask over at [Blender Artists](https://blenderartists.org) instead. Also take a look at http://topologyguides.com for a good starter.

Comment: It's hard to make a list that is not a collection of opinions. There is however a list of the **[frequently asked questions on this site](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/frequently-asked-questions-on-blender-stack-exchange)**, It might illustrate some of the recurring mistakes/misconceptions that new and old users have.